# Changing data source of a GridViewComboBox column Row-Wise

Tags: datagridview, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, radgridview

I'm working on a windows form application there I am using Rad Grid View. I'm stuck at a point, could any one of you please help me through this. Below is my scenario.

I have a grid which has 3 columns:

1. Role - GridViewComboBox column (it can be employee and intern)
2. Facility - GridViewComboBox column (For employee - it can be "a,b,c,d" and For intern it can be only "a,b")
3. Date - GridViewTextBox column (it is current date).

Scenario 1 :-

First row is

**Role   Facility       Date** (these are column header their respective values are below separated by space)

**Employee      d(selected_from_ComboBox)      01/11/2018**

Scenario 2 :-

I want 2nd row as

**Role       Facility    Date** (these are column header their respective values are below)

**Intern       b(selected_from_ComboBox)      01/11/2018**

When change facility column data source from "a,b,c,d"(for employee) to "a,b"(for intern) then facility selected for row 1 goes away since it is not in data source of intern ("a,b").

What should i do now?